# Control docker-compose in Java

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, docker-java

I created a fairly amount of docker-compose scripts which spawn up several services. I now want to control docker-compose in the JVM. Basically, I want to be able to execute `up` and `down`, ideally with `-p <project name>` parameter, so I can spawn multiple instances at the same time.

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: I found another useful library: https://www.testcontainers.org. *TestContainers is a Java library that supports JUnit tests, providing lightweight, throwaway instances of common databases, Selenium web browsers, or anything else that can run in a Docker container.*

Answer (score 4):

There might be two possible approaches that you can take:

1. Run docker-compose up/down using normal command executor (e.g. with the help of ProcessBuilder and run OS command)
2. Using native docker [SDK](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/), currently golang and python are officially supported, but java docker client can be found [here](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client) and [here](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java). For now, I am using docker SDK with golang, and see that we can programmatically do almost everything with docker.

Comment: Thank you! Regarding the second option: I already investigated these SDKs and 3rd party Java libraries you mentioned. They don't seem to support `docker-compose.yml` configurations and functionalities. So basically, I have to implement the `docker-compose` functionalities myself (parsing, starting containers, managing them, ...), which would be a massive task and reinventing the wheel. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Yeah, Docker SDK doesn't support docker-compose for now. However, we can still configure services one by one with the current SDK and group them together. We don't really need to implement entire dock-compose.yaml parsing and processing.

Comment: I will have to look into that!

Comment: Sure, I have done similar stuff to create cassandra cluster from golang, however, this is fairly simple and as each service/instance is identical. It might be troublesome if you have a complicated docker-compose setup.

Answer (score 2):

Docker Compose is a python utility that talks directly to the same Docker API as the all the other Docker clients. There's nothing fundamentally different about the commands it sends, but it does manage a lot of Docker container life cycle for you inside it's code.

Compose is based on the [`docker`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker) python module which is just another python Docker API client.

It would probably take a lot to reimplement the same in Java, [here is the `up` method](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/project.py#L426). Maybe try pulling that in with [Jython](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/EmbeddingJython) if you really need to do it from the JVM or stick with executing the `docker-compose` commands from Java.

Comment: thanks for your sharing, it's good to know. I should have used python SDK then :)

Comment: Most Docker tools would be written in Go normally. Compose was an external tool called *Fig* before it was bought by Docker and merged into the eco system.