# Convert docker-compose.yml to json that DockerAPI /services/create accepts?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, yaml, docker-api

I want to deploy service into already running Docker Stack via Docker API for Go-lang.

As dockerAPI only accepts json as described in their [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.33/#operation/ServiceCreate), I an searching for a tool that could covert compose.yaml to the json accepted by dockerAPI.

Alternatively, it would be great if there is any method in go-lang DockerAPI that can create service directly using yaml data as we provide in compose.yml.

Example Yaml:

`myapp:
  image: amithp/pyapp:latest
  deploy:
    replicas: 3
    restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
  networks:
    - frontend-network
  environment:
    - MYENV=myapp
  labels:
    myproject: "xyz"
    label1: "somevar"`

I am fairly new to both DockerAPI and Go-lang, any suggestion or direction will be greatly helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure it's one API call, compose does a lot of orchestration.  I'd start in the [service python](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/service.py).

Comment: I agreed with @Matt comment. The same discussion can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250271/control-docker-compose-in-java/47259018?noredirect=1#comment81500536_47259018. You can get one or two things

Comment: thanks for the info. I will take a look.